# Tantric Krishnaism?

Tags: krishna, tantra

I have heard about Sahajiya Vaishnava who follow Tantric form of Yoga in their Krishna-centred devotion ( cfr Dasgupta, Shashibhusan (1946, 1962 revised)' *Obscure Religious Cults as a Background to Bengali Literature*')
Other books? Name of prominent Gurus? Personal experiences?